# Compares the current OFFER or OFFERS?

Tags: grammatical-number

I've got a question since I struggle between "OFFER" and "OFFERS". Do I write:

1) It compares the current **offer** of the products on the market.

OR

2) It compares the current **offers** of the products on the market.

or something completely different?

Thanks a lot!

Mike

Comment: A comparison can only be made between a plural number of things. (Even if you compare your present self with your past self, you are still comparing to "different* selves.)

Comment: Mike X, how many offers, exactly, are you comparing, please?

Neither of your examples is acceptable but if the number of offers ws the point, how exactly could anyting compare one offer, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the [**offerings**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offering) from different vendors.

The word has its origins in religion, where it refers to something sacrificed in the hope that a supernatural being would notice and respond, but it's widely used in other contexts.  If you're a buyer, you may enjoy its connotations of omnipotence and the power to judge arbitrarily.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean offer as a deal or a discount! then:

> It compares different offers **on** the products of the market

Since you mean all products in the market, you could say

> It compares all the products on offer in the market.